# cant get glfw correctly imported

Tags: python, opengl, import, module, glfw

Currently I am trying to get glfw to work. Everytime I try to import it in python it raises

> Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.

I have downloaded glfw3 precompiled dll and placed it into the python DLLs folder but it still shows this error. I have also tried to install through easy_install but this error still occurs.

Comment: Is there a Python module for GLFW? Because if not, then Python (as far as I know) cannot read arbitrary C DLLs. And if there is such a module, then that's what you need to install.

Comment: I have totally forgot to mention, that I have installed a glfw module (1.1.2) for python. The error raises when I am trying to import this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have to put it into the python DLLs folder instead I have to copy the glfw3.dll which I have downloaded from glfw into system32 folder. Then the glfw module from python doesnt show any errors.